# Mysterious move

Tags: go, professional

I'm watching a NHK cup match between Hane Naoki and Chang Hsu with japanese commenters so unfortunately I can't understand the explanations, and there is a move from black I can't understand (move 3 in the diagram). The letters are other potential moves I would find more natural.

```
$$c
$$ --------------------
$$ -. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . 3 X . . . . a . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . O . . . X . . O . . O . . X . . .-  
$$ -. . . O . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . . . . . X . . . . . . . . . X . .-  
$$ -. . O . . . . . . . . . . . . b . . .-  
$$ -. . . . . . . . . . . . . . X . O . .-  
$$ -. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . O O . O . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . O X . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . X . X . . . . . . . . . O O O . .-  
$$ -. . X O X . . X . . . . . . O X X . .-  
$$ -. X O 1 X . . . . . . c . . O O X . .-  
$$ -. O 2 . . . . O . O . . . . . X X . .-  
$$ -. . O . X . . . . . . . X . . . O . .-  
$$ -. . . . . X . O . X . . . . . O . . .-  
$$ -. . . O . . . . . . . . . . X X X . .-  
$$ -. . . . . d . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ -. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .-  
$$ ---------------------
```

So I have two questions :

1) How many points is worth black move ? (Maybe that's too early to decide). A player stronger than me (~3kyu, I'm ~13kyu) told me these kind of moves were worth ~15 points  but I was not convinced.

2) What is the exact meaning of this move, and why play it instead of e.g the other moves indicated ? I feel the purpose is stabilize the black group and making points, but playing on the other side seems more interesting to me as it's also potentially taking away white basis.

Comment: It would be great if you could make your question self-contained. The markdown allows us to insert board positions. You can look at some other Go questions to see how it's done, it's unfortunately not documented in the markdown help. This will greatly help us understand, what kind of move you are actually asking about.

Comment: Here is a post that uses this markdown syntax: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/revisions/42049/4 The raw markdown of this post is available here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/revisions/8631aa22-3d00-4833-b523-a3de5cf40756/view-source

Comment: There's an instruction on how to use the markdown in the [tag wiki](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/go/info).

Comment: @Glorfindel ... which also just links to another site for the actual documentation. The place where this should be documented, is the help that's shown when you click on the question mark symbol in the markdown editor of this site. Obviously, that's nothing you or I can fix, that's up to the people running Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Forget I was ever here : thanks for your edit ! I didn't see it as I was copying the game. Maybe my edit is better since people can modify the codes, and moreover I could add several alternative moves that seem more natural to me. But your edit is really appreciated thanks a lot !

Comment: No apology necessary - my edit was only meant to be temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will concentrate on the question **3** vs. **a**. While a move at **a** will also settle black's top left group, it helps the two white stones to make shape and build up pressure towards blacks top right corner. It also takes out other possibilities of attacking the two white stones like building a black wall towards the centre. On the other hand, **3** is a perfect move, it has a large continuation move at b17 when white does not answer (not necessarily played out immediately, but it is there).

And I think that fixing the weak black groups has priority over going for pure profit on the board, given the whole-board situation.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I perfectly understand but I'm only 12 kyu so it will surely become clear later.